# Prove the uniform convergence of the sequence of real valued function

Tags: uniform-convergence

$$f_n=xe^{-nx^2}, x\in R, n\in N.$$
Prove that the sequence {${f_n}$} is uniformly convergent in $R$. Some good arguments to prove this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** It converges pointwise to $0$. Now recall the definition of uniform convergence and find the supremum of $f_n(x)$ by maximizing it (you should get $e^{-1/2}/\sqrt{2n}$).

Comment: The supremum of $f_n$ is $\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}e^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes you are correct, good catch, forgot the constant.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Further this supremum clearly tends to 0 as $n\to \infty$ which is same as the point limit. Hence $f_n\to f=0$ uniformly on $R$

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Sir can you please review [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524678/point-of-non-uniform-convergence) question.